# How do we break extended, hours-long lock on 440K+ messages in a Dead-Letter Queue?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Some of our Dead-Letter Queues have e.g., 440K messages available in Peak mode but zero available in PeakLock mode. If I understand correctly, that means the Service Bus has locked those 440K messages.

- We do not know what has these locked.
- These have remained locked for several hours.

*How can we unlock 'em?*

We see the same behavior through the .NET SDK as we do here in the Service Bus Explorer.

[image: 440K messages locked in Service Bus Explorer]

Here we have an example of *one* of those messages. It has a GUID value for its `LockToken` and a `LockedUntil` from the past. How can we unlock this message?

[image]

## Research

We thought the system had "pinned" these messages.

> The [lock] token can also be used to pin the lock permanently through the Deferral API.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage.locktoken

That seems unlikely, though, because the messages have a `State` property of `Active` not `Deferred`.

Comment: A message cannot be locked for longer than 5 mins unless there's an active process constantly attempting to PeekLock messages. At least these days. So it's something on the broker. It looks like you have an issue with the DLQ. I suggest opening a support case, as the community cannot help with these issues.

Comment: This tends to happen if we throw say 1,000 receivers at a the DLQ at once or if we set a large prefetch count. I wonder whether the broker finds this tough and ends up freezing on us.

Comment: 5000 connections according to the docs should be ok. If you disconnect all receivers, do DLQ messages become available?

Comment: I know, right? So when we disconnect all receivers, DLQ messages do not become available. To make 'em available, we either have to wait for several hours OR to toggle the topic from `Active` -> `Disabled` -> `Active`.